# python - How to know what re used to split a string?

Tags: python, regex

The code below lets a user input two names of movies separated by either `&`, `|` or `^`:

```
query = raw_input("Enter your query:")
movie_f = re.split('&|\^|\|', query)[0].strip()
movie_s = re.split('&|\^|\|', query)[1].strip()
```

I want to know what `re` has used to separate the string (`&`, `|` or `^`). How can i do that?

Comment: Why do you *want to know*?

Comment: @jamylak for example if it's a `&` I want to return the actors that played in both movies. If it's `^` I want to return all actors from both movies, etc

Comment: i dont see any problem here. You will have the result in a list with the second item as the separator.
`sep = re.split(r'(&|^|\|)', query)[1]`
Put a condition on that as you desire

Comment: You actually want `match` here rather than `split`: `movie_1,operator,movie_2 = re.match('(.+?)([&|^])(.+)', query).groups()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you group the regex it will return the items it split by for every second item.

```
>>> query
'&foo^bar'
>>> re.split(r'(&|\^|)', query)
['', '&', 'foo', '^', 'bar']
```

Comment: @Tom It means raw string, you should use them when working with regex since some of the symbols eg. `\\` get interpreted incorrectly without them.